# Definition of ssé

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire

In Stromae’s song, “[avf](https://youtu.be/q9hW4MLNp5E)”, Maître Gims says

> J'ai rien de ssé-ca

What does “ssé” mean in this context?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

He is actually using [verlan](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/verlan/81556). In this slang, "ssé-ca" is the translation of "cassé". Therefore, what he means is:

> J'ai rien de cassé

Meaning "[I'm fine](https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/63959)", or litterally "I have no broken bones".